# String comparison not work in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString *psgn;  
psgn = @"/";  
if([psgn isEqualToString:@"/"]) // Did not work.  
{  
  val = val + [tb1.text doubleValue];  
}
```

How I compare this string.

Comment: There is no problem....try to add breakpoint inside if statment

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the comparison.  I'd put in some NSLogs to see what VAL is before and after the assignment, and what the result of [tb1.text doubleValue] is too.  I suspect what's going on here is you're assuming that the comparison isn't working because the value that's being incremented isn't as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I do not find any wrong in your code, but just wanted to edit a bit. you could have written

```
NSString *psgn = @"/";          //you can combine 2 line of your code into single
if([psgn isEqualToString:@"/"]) // Did not work.  
{  
   val = val + [tb1.text doubleValue];  
}else{
   NSLog(@"What's the value of psgn %@ then, after condition fails");
}
```